# Rails - Query Composite Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, composite-primary-key

I have a table in my database which uses composite keys.  To implement it in rails, I used the gem ['composite_primary_keys'](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) to implement this feature.

I have two primary keys - CompanyID, KeypersonID in the model CompanyKeyperson.

Now, if I want to find all the keypeople with CompanyID=1, how do I do it?

Something like -

```
    CompanyKeyperson.find(1,*)
```

which obviously throws an error.

Comment: Please try `CompanyKeyperson.where(CompanyID: 1)`.

Comment: Thanks you!  That works.